# Use Native Storage in service

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I installed [Native Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/). So I have to use it on `home.ts` (component). this is my Code

```
  setStyle (val: string) {
    this.nativeStorage.setItem('style', {color: val})
    .then(
      () => console.log('Stored item!'),
      error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
    );
  }

  getStyle (property: string) {
    this.nativeStorage.getItem('style')
    .then(
      data => console.log(data[property]),
      error => console.error(error)
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setStyle('fff');
    this.getStyle('color');
  }
```

when I run my app using `ionic cordova run browser` my code works good. And I see in console this

```
Stored item!
fff
```

**But my problem here** when I use Native Storage at `style.ts` (service)

```
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';

export class Style {

  constructor(private nativeStorage: NativeStorage) {}

  set (val: string) {
    this.nativeStorage.setItem('style', {color: val})
    .then(
      () => console.log('Stored item!'),
      error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
    );
  }

  get (property: string) {
    this.nativeStorage.getItem('style')
    .then(
      data => console.log(data[property]),
      error => console.error(error)
    );
  }

}
```

and use my service in `home.ts` (component)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Style } from '../../style/style';

export class HomePage implements OnInit{

  constructor(private style: Style) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.style.set('fff');
    this.style.get('color');
  }

}
```

I got this error on console

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Style: (?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:466)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:15547)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:15382)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (compiler.js:15362)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (compiler.js:15722)
    at compiler.js:15633
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.js:15593)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15161)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:33542)
```

However when I use not constructor my code workig

```
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';

export class Style {

  set (val: string) {
    new NativeStorage().setItem('style', {color: val})
    .then(
      () => console.log('Stored item!'),
      error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
    );
  }

  get (property: string) {
    new NativeStorage().getItem('style')
    .then(
      data => console.log(data[property]),
      error => console.error(error)
    );
  }

}
```

**My Question is How to use Native Storage in service with constructor 
 and avoid this error `Can't resolve all parameters for Style: (?)`**

Comment: @Injectable()
you need to flag your service with @Injectable() 
and then list it in the providers array 


http://jbavari.github.io/blog/2015/10/19/angular-2-injectables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the flag @Injectable() above your service class declaration.

Documentation: [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)